# Access sessionStorage in template EmberJS

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have saved some data in sessionStorage (a large JSON response from ajax) in EmberJS, and wanted to know if there was a way to access that directly in template handlebars. If not, what would be my alternatives? I have tried `{{sessionStorage.getItem("data"}}` in template but it gives me an error saying "**Expecting 'ID', got 'INVALID'**".

Comment: Oh that's just a typo, let me correct that. It's not in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the item in sessionStorage to a variable in your component.js like this:

```
init:function(){
  this.set('sessionStorageData', sessionStorage.getItem('data'));
}
```

and use it in your hbs like this:

```
{{sessionStorageData}}
```

Comment: Not working, says undefined when I log it in handlebars

Comment: **Update** There was an issue with my `model`. It works when I fixed it! Sorry for the late response Thanks!